# Python: Serialize a bottle request

Tags: python, bottle

As title, basically. I have a LocalRequest from a Bottle app. How would I serialize it, send it to a different machine, and then deserialize it back into a LocalRequest?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried pickle?